# Combine variables with text to make variable

Tags: variable, set

How can I create a variable that is a combination of two variables with text?

For example, I know the following is wrong but is something like this possible:

```
{% set foo = 'foo' %}
{% set bar = 'bar' %}
{% set foobar = 'Hello' foo,bar %}
{{ foobar }} #Outputs Hello foobar
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can concatenate variables like this:

```
{% set foo = 'foo' %}
{% set bar = 'bar' %}
{% set foobar = 'Hello' ~ foo ~ bar %}
{{ foobar }} #Outputs Hello foobar
```

It's explained by Brandon [here](https://github.com/brandonkelly/TwigForDesigners/blob/master/values-expressions-and-variables.md#expressions).

Comment: Perfect thanks! Thank you for the resource too, very helpful!